JavaScript calendar with saving several time intervals and dates
I have custom post type - specialists.
Please help me find a javascript calendar in which I would be able to choose the dates and times of several sessions in the admin panel, and then save them for each specialist separately in WordPress, so that it can be used later in the booking form.
Example of recording session dates and times
13:00 - 15:00 08/16/2024
16:00 - 17:00 08/16/2024
10:00 - 13:00 08/17/2024


One of the things we are not supposed to do is suggest Libraries to others as it just causes arguments about which is best
